# connect-direct iseries to mainframe (NDM) setup

Tags: ibm-midrange, connect-direct

I'm setting up Connect:Direct, to exchange files with a mainframe (NDM).  When we send a test file (COPYCF) from the mainframe, I can see data coming from the mainframe side in the TCPIP packets (we captured the conversation and looked at the packets in WireShark) but I don't see any data in the packets coming out of the iSeries.  The TCPIP headers look good, but there's no data.  It's like C:D isn't able to talk in the conversation.

Does this sound like I missed something in my Node setup, or some other detail?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to start TCP/IP DRDA on the IBM i side? (STRTCPSVR *DDM) If it's not that, does it look as if the IBM i listener has been spoken to (NETSTAT *CNN, find the listener, see how long ago it last did anything). (I can't remember what C:D does but I imagine it talks DRDA over TCP/IP.)

Comment: for 'DRDA' read 'DRDA or DDM' throughout in the above!